Can't reduce val_loss when teaching computer vision
I tried everything, improved the architecture, added layers, neurons, but it doesn’t work. Could this be because I'm training images at 384x384 resolution?
    import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

classes = 5

# Функция для загрузки и предобработки изображений из папки
def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    labels = []
    class_names = os.listdir(folder)
    for class_name in class_names:
        class_path = os.path.join(folder, class_name)
        for filename in os.listdir(class_path):
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(class_path, filename))
            if img is not None:
                img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))  # Изменение размера до 64x64
                img = img.astype('float32') / 255
                images.append(img)
                labels.append(class_names.index(class_name))
    return np.array(images), to_categorical(np.array(labels), classes), labels

# Load and preprocess images from the dataset folder
dataset_folder = 'E:\\MSHI_2_KYRS_2_SIM\\5.v5\\dataset\\train'
x_train, y_train, y_labels = load_images_from_folder(dataset_folder)

# Split data into training and testing sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# Calculate class weights
class_weights = dict(enumerate(compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced', classes=np.unique(y_labels), y=y_labels)))

# Create and compile the model

# Create and compile the model with weighted loss
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


# Train the model with class weights
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), class_weight=class_weights)


# Save and load the model as before

# Save the model
save_path = 'E:\\MSHI_2_KYRS_2_SIM\\5.v5\\my_model.keras'
model.save(save_path)

# Load the model
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(save_path)

# Load and preprocess an image for prediction
img_path = 'E:\\MSHI_2_KYRS_2_SIM\\5.v5\\dataset\\train\\healthy\\20220101_085747_jpg.rf.8e8f3a8931b9f5a43b77e87937b875a7.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))
img = img.astype('float32') / 255
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

# Make predictions using the loaded model
predictions = loaded_model.predict(img)
class_names = ['algal', 'brown_blight', 'gray_blight', 'healthy', 'red_spot']
predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions)
predicted_class_name = class_names[predicted_class]
predicted_prob = predictions[0][predicted_class]

print('Predicted class:', predicted_class_name)
print('Probability:', predicted_prob)





Epoch 1/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3s 47ms/step - accuracy: 0.1800 - loss: 1.6678 - val_accuracy: 0.3012 - val_loss: 1.5612
Epoch 2/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.3546 - loss: 1.4837 - val_accuracy: 0.3775 - val_loss: 1.3366
Epoch 3/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.3527 - loss: 1.4189 - val_accuracy: 0.4458 - val_loss: 1.2974
Epoch 4/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.4015 - loss: 1.2905 - val_accuracy: 0.5582 - val_loss: 1.1519
Epoch 5/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.4741 - loss: 1.2249 - val_accuracy: 0.6345 - val_loss: 1.0815
Epoch 6/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.5274 - loss: 1.1392 - val_accuracy: 0.6305 - val_loss: 1.0546
Epoch 7/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 30ms/step - accuracy: 0.5744 - loss: 1.0751 - val_accuracy: 0.6345 - val_loss: 0.9895
Epoch 8/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.6253 - loss: 1.0424 - val_accuracy: 0.6345 - val_loss: 0.9201
Epoch 9/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 30ms/step - accuracy: 0.5834 - loss: 1.0626 - val_accuracy: 0.6747 - val_loss: 0.9016
Epoch 10/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.6576 - loss: 0.8760 - val_accuracy: 0.6747 - val_loss: 0.8456
Epoch 11/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 33ms/step - accuracy: 0.6317 - loss: 0.8696 - val_accuracy: 0.6586 - val_loss: 0.8808
Epoch 12/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 30ms/step - accuracy: 0.6426 - loss: 0.8469 - val_accuracy: 0.7068 - val_loss: 0.8178
Epoch 13/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.6738 - loss: 0.7729 - val_accuracy: 0.5904 - val_loss: 1.0304
Epoch 14/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 32ms/step - accuracy: 0.6776 - loss: 0.8323 - val_accuracy: 0.7149 - val_loss: 0.8181
Epoch 15/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 32ms/step - accuracy: 0.7252 - loss: 0.6729 - val_accuracy: 0.6867 - val_loss: 0.7835
Epoch 16/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 32ms/step - accuracy: 0.7558 - loss: 0.6813 - val_accuracy: 0.7269 - val_loss: 0.8004
Epoch 17/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.7109 - loss: 0.6636 - val_accuracy: 0.6867 - val_loss: 0.8329
Epoch 18/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 33ms/step - accuracy: 0.7475 - loss: 0.6015 - val_accuracy: 0.7108 - val_loss: 0.8273
Epoch 19/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 32ms/step - accuracy: 0.7663 - loss: 0.6021 - val_accuracy: 0.7229 - val_loss: 0.7504
Epoch 20/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 33ms/step - accuracy: 0.7462 - loss: 0.5803 - val_accuracy: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.9694
Epoch 21/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.7682 - loss: 0.5598 - val_accuracy: 0.7028 - val_loss: 0.8124
Epoch 22/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.8133 - loss: 0.4916 - val_accuracy: 0.7269 - val_loss: 0.7957
Epoch 23/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 33ms/step - accuracy: 0.8201 - loss: 0.4763 - val_accuracy: 0.6988 - val_loss: 0.8507
Epoch 24/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 33ms/step - accuracy: 0.8063 - loss: 0.4616 - val_accuracy: 0.7309 - val_loss: 0.7837
Epoch 25/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 35ms/step - accuracy: 0.8704 - loss: 0.3862 - val_accuracy: 0.7108 - val_loss: 0.8784
Epoch 26/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 33ms/step - accuracy: 0.8719 - loss: 0.3722 - val_accuracy: 0.7028 - val_loss: 0.9467
Epoch 27/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.8673 - loss: 0.3757 - val_accuracy: 0.7349 - val_loss: 0.8438
Epoch 28/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 32ms/step - accuracy: 0.8545 - loss: 0.3687 - val_accuracy: 0.6867 - val_loss: 1.0415
Epoch 29/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 30ms/step - accuracy: 0.8504 - loss: 0.3589 - val_accuracy: 0.7229 - val_loss: 0.8642
Epoch 30/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 32ms/step - accuracy: 0.8945 - loss: 0.3146 - val_accuracy: 0.7149 - val_loss: 0.8812
Epoch 31/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.8421 - loss: 0.3840 - val_accuracy: 0.7108 - val_loss: 1.0181
Epoch 32/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 30ms/step - accuracy: 0.9033 - loss: 0.2608 - val_accuracy: 0.7108 - val_loss: 0.9892
Epoch 33/50
19/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 31ms/step - accuracy: 0.9207 - loss: 0.2226 - val_accuracy: 0.6787 - val_loss: 1.0831
Epoch 34/50
15/19 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 26ms/step - accuracy: 0.8765 - loss: 0.2960Traceback (most recent call last):


Please explain your problem in the question.

It'd really help if you included the error message in addition to the code
